# Android Menu Button on 4.0 Devices

Tags: android

If my target SDK is set to 11 and I am using Theme.Holo.NoActionBar, is there any way to get my menu to appear? I am using Theme.Holo for larger screens such as tablets, but purely in the interest of saving screen space, I'd like to not show the Action Bar on smartphones.

However, I don't know if some sort of "soft" menu button appears in this case like it does for apps targeted at earlier versions. I'm not sure if the emulator shows a realistic device screen layout, and I don't have a 4.0 phone (i.e., a Nexus) to try it on (and I'll have to wait a while to get one unless AT&T eventually gets the Nexus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a soft Options Menu button which appears on a 4.0 device, see the attached screenshot.
Three Vertical dots on the bottom right corner represent the Options Menu. They only appear if your app has an options menu.

![image: screenshot of weather app running on Galaxy Nexus]

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a problem a while back by assuming that devices would always have a Search hardkey, so I was concerned here. I just hope that users who never RTFM (99% of them!) will find this since it's not exactly obvious what it does. I can't believe how many of my users comment "if only it had such-and-such feature" and I answer back "Have you ever pressed the menu button?"

Answer (score 13):

Note that the three dots (aka 'overflow') will not show up at the bottom if you set targetSdkVersion >= 14.

Comment: Does this mean there's no access to the overflow menu, or does it show up in some other way? But FWIW, I doubt I'll target 14 directly any time soon.

Comment: Search the word 'overflow' here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html . The overflow menu includes the action bar items that do not show in the action bar. You have some control what will show on the action bar and what will be left to the overflow menu. As for migration, I feel your pain. I was in exactly the same situation until added an overflow icon to my app (no action bar) and conditioned it with api >= 10. It opens a custom dialog with a list of my menu actions. I wish the migration to ICS features would be easier.