# Not Showing Any Sign of Menu Button when there is not any default menu button in devices

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, menuitem

I am Working on One Application which has `Settings` Screen which Opens When User Click on OptionMenu Shortcut which shows on Devices as Default Button or any other Sign.

it Works fine when there is default menu button in device but not getting any Sign for Menu Option when there is not any default menu button in devices.

My Code is as Below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.btnSettingMenu:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                RegisterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("From", "MainActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have refered to Link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264076/android-menu-button-on-4-0-devices) but could not able to solve my problem.

**Point I would like to add is:** I am getting the Menu Option in Emulator when i am pressing `PageUp` or `F2`.

But when the Device Does not have Default Menu Button it is not Showing with any other indication as three dots or some other way.

**My Question :** How can User Go to my Setting Screen if he is not Finding Option Menu Sign in real devices Like Nexus 7?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing Menu icon in `above 4.0 Devices`:

if you have declared `android:targetSdkVersion="xx"`

Either remove it if you don't required.

**OR**

If you want to declare it,then set value 0f `xx` below **14**

```
i.e.android:targetSdkVersion="13".
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Please remove this two line in your java class.

   ```
   // hide titlebar of application
   // must be before setting the layout
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   // hide statusbar of Android
   // could also be done later
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   ```
2. Please remove this two line in your AndroidManifest.xml.

   To hide the titlebar of your application you can use the predefined style

   ```
   android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar”.
   ```

   or if you also want to hide the statusbar of your application use

   ```
   android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen”.
   ```

Comment: Please stop using bold for 90% of your text. Less is more in this case!